# How to rewrite this using 2 FOR loops?

Tags: python, loops

Here is the snippet. How can I re-write this to do away with the first `WHILE` loop?

```
start = 1
end = 4
currentcount = 0
while start < end:

    file = open('C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\\test' + str(start) + '.txt')
    for line in file:    

        f = o.open('http://www.test.com/?userid=' + line.strip())
        f.close()
        time.sleep(10)

        currentcount += 1

    start += 1
```

Comment: Also check your backslashes (\\). You might need two of them everywhere, not just before `\\test`.

Comment: @Dave oh really? ok thanks! whats the reason behind that? just good practise?

Comment: \ is used to begin escape sequences, such as \n for newline. \\ is the sequence to get a backslash. Invalid sequences are usually handled by assuming you meant a backslash, but you don't want the program to change meaning from new sequences being defined. Use r in front to disable the escape sequences entirely: `r'c:...\test'` would not change \t to a tab.

Comment: Instead of `time.sleep(10)` use `time.sleep(random.randint(5,15))` if you want to mimic human behavior. The resulting behavior for a large number of lines in file should be equivalent, but it will prevent the http server from treating you like a web crawler and limiting the number of requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your while loop to this:

```
for i in range(start, end):
```

Then use `i` in the method body. Other points:

- Using `start` as a counter is potentially confusing. If you change the value of `start` it is no longer the start.
- Use a raw string for the path:
  `r'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\test'`
- Consider using `str.format` to build the string rather than string concatenation.

In Python 2.x `xrange` can be slightly more efficient than `range`, although that probably isn't a significant issue here given the size of the numbers involved.

Comment: side topic. can I rewrite most `while` loops into `for` loops? If so, what's the point of using a `while` loop?

Comment: @Nai: A while loop is useful when you don't know in advance how many iterations there will be.

Answer (score 1):

```
currentcount = 0  
for i in range(1, 4):      
    file = open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\test' + str(i) + '.txt')      
    for line in file:               
        f = o.open('http://www.test.com/?userid=' + line.strip())          
        f.close()          
        time.sleep(10)            
        currentcount += 1
```

You could use some other list iteration/lambda methods, but this should be what you're looking for as it eliminates the outer while loop and is still easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
currentCount = 0
for start in range(1, 4):
    file = open('C:\\Users\Owner\\Desktop\\test' + str(start) + '.txt')
    for line in file:    

        f = o.open('http://www.test.com/?userid=' + line.strip())
        f.close()
        time.sleep(10)

        currentcount += 1
```

Comment: Don't forget `currentcount = 0`!

Comment: @Ken: Oh yeah. Edited to add that back in. Thanks!

Comment: And everything from the second `for` onwards is too indented and you need to drop the `start += 1`

Comment: @Day: Agh. Thanks. This is what I get for manually inserting spaces. :)

Comment: Do I need to still include `start += 1` ?

Comment: @Nai: No. The for loop will increment it for you.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more complicated, but handles the most likely errors and keeps on trucking:

```
import time
import random

ids      = range(4)
infName  = 'c:/Users/Owner/Desktop/test{0}.txt'.format
outfAddr = 'http://www.test.com/?userid={0}'.format
delay    = lambda: time.sleep(random.randint(5,15))

filecount = 0
usercount = 0
for i in ids:
    try:
        with open(infName(i), 'r') as inf:
            filecount += 1
            for line in inf:
                try:
                    with o.open(outfAddr(line.strip())) as outf:
                        usercount += 1
                except IOError:
                    pass
                delay()
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

My take:

```
start = 1
end = 4

for count in range(start,end):
    file_name=r'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\test' + str(count) + '.txt'
    with open(file_name) as file:
        for line in file:    
            with o.open('http://www.test.com/?userid=' + line.strip()) as f:
               pass
            time.sleep(10)
```